# How to json encode ajax result using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax page which will contain form function and also dynamic html code. please check the below example have to jsonencode the results but the forms is in dynamic format cant get it worked.

```
 //getting_result.php
require_once('include/form.class.php');
 $rowid = $_POST['rowid']; // database row id to retrieve the content
 $getjson_form = getJsonForm($rowid); // will get the jsonform name
 $form = new Form(['file'=>$getjson_form[0]['json_form_name']]); 
  // will show the form 
  ouput <div class="form-row" id="form_output_row"><div class="form-group col-md-6">//   
     
$pagecontents = file_get_contents("llor.html");
     $get_form = $form->show();
 $total_output = array("json_form_name"=>$get_form);
 echo json_encode($total_output,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

 mypage for ajax jquery
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                 url : "getting_result.php",
                data    : {rowid:id },
                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                success: function(data){
                   console.log(data.json_form_name);
                   //$("#jsonformname").html(data.json_form_name);                    
                   var find_form = $(data).filter('#form_output_row');
                   console.log(find_form);
                   $("#jsonformname").html(data.json_form_name);                    
                   
                  // $("#terms_cond").html(data.terms_condi);

                   }
              });
```

Comment: Somewhat unclear, please confirm:  You want to take a json string from your service, have jquery convert it to an object (`dataType:"json"`) and *then* take that object and convert it back to a json string?   Just remove `dataType:"json"` and your `data` will the the json string from the server.   Perhaps you could explain what you want to do with the string once you've encoded it?

Comment: actually json form function will show raw form ouput i cannot encode it.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what "*json form function*" is.  There's nothing in your code that indicates what this might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`JSON.stringify(data);`